# Как поменять денежные знаки в C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, консоль, локализация

[image: Это моя задача (код)]

[image: Вот что выводит в консоль]

Как поменять денежные знаки в C#. Прочитал разные ранние ответы на этот вопрос в других комьюнити. Но решение не нашёл

Моя задача: научиться, вместо знака вопроса (кракозябры), выводить валюту какого-то другого региона (например доллары, гривны и тд.)!

Что я уже делал ранее:

1. Менял регион через настройки ПК. Путь к параметру Регион/ Дополнительные параметры даты, времени, региона/ Региональные стандарты/ Дополнительно/ Изменить язык системы/ Английский (США)
2. Поменял кодировку консоли на, **65001 - Кодировка UTF-8**

[image: Текущая кодовая страница]

Comment: `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`

Comment: [CultureInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Подскажите, в какую часть кода C# это нужно вписывать?

Comment: Я разобрался: 
   1. Cначала нужно добавить в начало кода using System.Globalization
   2. Прописать любую культуру (их можно найти в интернете) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    en-US ----  это культура США, можно менять на любую другую доступную

Answer (score 0):

Кодировку консоли можно поменять непосредственно в коде:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

---

Чтобы выводился нужный символ валюты по строке формата `c`, необходимо задать желаемую культуру: [CultureInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-6.0).

Сделать это можно как глобально:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
// или
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

так и задавая желаемую культуру непосредственно в методах форматирования:

```
var formatProvider = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

Console.WriteLine(string.Format(formatProvider, "{0:c}", price));
Console.WriteLine(price.ToString("c", formatProvider));
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!